# How to store the check marks (ticks) in array list so that when I open it again I can retain the check marks

Tags: java, android-studio

So basically I am making an App which stores my To Do List ,I wanna check mark (tick) the tasks I have completed that is shown in the array list but I don't really understand how to store the values or How to apply tick mark without using on Click function.

My problem is when I come back to this activity all tick marks are gone

On main block declartions

```
String m_Text;
static ArrayList<String> toDoList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView listView;
boolean wannaDelete = false;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
static int completed, left;
```

Inside onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,toDoList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)view;
            String msg;

            if(textview.isChecked()) {
                completed--;
            } else {
                completed++;
            }

            textview.setChecked(!textview.isChecked());
            left = toDoList.size() - completed;

            if (left == 0) {
                msg = "completed all your Task";
            } else {
                msg = "Only " + Integer.toString(left) + " more :)";
            }

            Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this type of scenario you have to take Arraylist of custom class and in that class take 2 variable one your string and another boolean for your chackmark status.

```
Ex. 
public class Data {
  string name;
  Boolean checkAvailabe ;
 }
```

Comment: but how to set check mark outside setOnItemClickListener ,can you please share the syntax

Comment: for that you can set value on particulate index of array and notifyadapter

Comment: here i found example.https://www.dev2qa.com/android-custom-listview-with-checkbox-example/